# search for similar phone numbers in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a collection of phone numbers in a column. I want to identify similar ones in the column. The similarity rule would be the first 8 digits are the same and the last two digits are in sequence (at least 3 numbers).

For example,

```
8601116612
8601116613
8601116614
```

The three numbers above should be identified as being similar. How can I do this in VBA?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Are there any particular problems you are having?

Comment: Are you only searching for vba or would you be open to a formula?

Comment: Easy - grab a number and loop through the column to find any cells where the first 8 digits are equal

Comment: How do you want to identify them? Also do you only want to identify similar numbers that are in sequence in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, this was kinda frustrating, but here it is:

```
Sub findSims()

Dim i, j, rc, rc1 As Double
Dim m, z As Double

i = 1
m = 0
z = 0

Do While Cells(i, 1) <> ""

' calculate the value of the last two digits
' for educational reasons one calculation

rc = Right(Cells(i, 1), 2)
rc1 = Right(Cells(i + 1, 1), 2) - 1

' .. and one direct comparation ..
' .. of the first 8 digits and afterwards the first two

If Left(Cells(i, 1), 8) = Left(Cells(i + 1, 1), 8) Then
    If rc = rc1 Then

' there are two counters because we have to wait until we have three similar numbers
        m = m + 1
        z = z + 1
    Else
' if the similarities stop, we kill m
    m = 0
' we use z to write this cutie of a sentence (you can insert here whatever you like)
    If z > 1 Then
        Cells(i, 2) = "The Cells from A" & i & " to A" & (i - z) & " are similar."
    End If
    z = 0
 End If
End If

' increment i and the job is done
i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

This seems kinda clunky and theres probably a better solution, but thats the best I came up with. Have fun.

Comment: There's an error when it loops to the last record. And I guess I need to sort the numbers first to make this work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It loops as long there is some kind of data in the cells, if there's a cell without data, it stops. You can choose any other break, just put it into the `Do While YourBreakCondition`. You can sort the data with the Sort button in the ribbon.